# How to synchronize access to an index of an array

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I am writing two progrms that simulate a banking service. There's the server program and the user program. The server sets up multiple threads that function as "eletronic counters" that read the user's requests and do as they say.

The user's accounts are stored on the server inside an array and they can be accessed depending on the requests. My problem is the following: imagine thread A is transfering money from John to Maria. How can I stop the other threads from accessing John's and Maria's account while the transaction is taking place? I know about semaphores, mutexes and condition variables, but I can't find a way to use them in a way that doesn't block the access to the entire array.

EDIT: I was told to create N mutexes, where N = number of accounts, and have each mutex associated with an account. Is there a better solution to solve this problem?

Comment: hint - mutex and semaphore. Run the intermediate process which will hold and process all the exclusions. You can also have mutex assiosiated with the array element

Comment: @P__J__ what do you mean by "Run the intermediate process which will hold and process all the exclusions"? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options, among them:

### Option 1

Give every account its own mutex.  Ensure that when a thread wants to lock two records (e.g. for a transfer) that it always looks them in the same order -- e.g. lowest number first.

Threads will then simply acquire the mutexes of the records they need to modify (always observing correct locking order to avoid deadlock), make their modifications, and then release the mutexes.

### Option 2

Roll your own record-level locks.  Establish a variable for each account recording whether that account is locked.  This can be inside the account array or in a separate data structure.  Use a single mutex to protect access to all the lock flags, and a CV to assist threads in waiting for a lock to become available.

Threads then operate in this pattern:

1. Lock the mutex.
2. If all required records are unlocked then turn on the their lock flags and go to step 4.
3. Wait on the CV, then go back to step 2.
4. *Release the mutex*
5. Perform all (other) account modifications
6. Re-lock the mutex
7. Turn off all the record locks acquired in step 2.
8. Broadcast to the CV and release the mutex.

---

Option 2 has more thread contention than does option 1, and therefore probably somewhat less concurrency in practice, but that is the tradeoff involved in using only one mutex.  You could address that to some extent with a hybrid solution that divided the accounts into groups, and implemented option 2 on a per-group basis.